# How to increase the size of the booleanfield in flask form?

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am making a flask form that contains multiple checkbox. I have this code in the form.py file.

> var_name = BooleanField('', default=False)

And I have this in the html.

`<p>{{ var_name }}</p>`

The checkbox that I get on the browser is too small. I guess it is the default size. How do I increase the size of the checkbox? Thank you

Comment: Can you post an image of what you mean by "too small"? Normally you would size an element with CSS, but form elements often don't need to be resized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is, using a hint taken from the WTForms docs [here](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html), is add a class to the field::

```
var_name(class_ = "checkbox")
```

Then style it with CSS:

```
.checkbox {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is truly simple for beginners like myself. I gave this solution an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can user an inline style for a single element:

```
<p>{{ var_name(style="height: 25px;width: 25px;") }}</p>
```